# Homepage of my e-commerce store is always displayed first, then the appropriate categories

Tags: seo, homepage, categories

I have an e-commerce store, which sells wedding dresses, suits, costumes etc. I have the title of my homepage set like this:

```
The store name | [name of the 4 main categories delimited with coma]
```

Then, in the description I have all the important keywords.

It works great, however, when I type the "wedding dresses [city name]" to Google, I would expect the category page to show up - insted the homepage is always shown with higher priority.

I could probably fix this by making the homepage title and description less specific - but than again, based on KW analysis I don't really want to do that, since there really are just a few keywords that really seem to work, and those are basically category names.

What would be the best approach?

Comment: Stuffing a comma separated list of keywords into your home page title is not a good SEO practice to begin with in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

On your home page, you presumably talk about your service (category) offerings in **natural language**, not keyword stuffing or lists.  It is here that you should be including links to the relevant wedding dress categories and providing links to your category page.  The context in which your subpages are linked to adds weight to their relevance.